# How to add an exception to a mod_rewrite rule (wordpress site)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress website im trying to call a php script that is located on the website the URL is something like this

http://example.com/folder/process.php

The problem is when I try to do this i always get redirected to the themes "not found" page.
This is the htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

If i put a test.html file in that directory it will work, and show the contents of the .html file. I think it has something to do with the .php extension it doesn't like?

If i call example.com/wp-config.php it finds that file and deosnt show a 404 page..

Comment: Are there any rules or an htaccess file in the `/folder/` directory?

Comment: no none i just made the "folder" to place this 1 process.php file in

Answer (score 1):

This Rule says "If request starts with index.php, do not rewrite and stop".

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

Immediately before or after that line you could add something like

```
RewriteRule ^process\.php$ - [L]
```

To not rewrite requests to that particular file.

Note that you will have to put your file next to Wordpress' index.php for this to work properly.

Comment: I put it in the same directory as the index.php Not right next to it because cpanel is alphabetical order. Still doesn't work.

Comment: And you added the above rule as well?

Comment: i think it was a file permissions problem i explained it below. No idea why this would be the case..but thats the beauty of programming, all its got to be is 1 tiny think ti make everything not work

Answer (score 0):

Change your .htaccess to this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/+folder/process\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Sill does the same, this is the exact reason why i don't use WordPress anymore. I think it has something to do with with .php ext because if i put a .html file in the same folder it will show the contents of that .html file.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off mod_rewrite altogether in your `/folder/` directory by creating an htaccess file in there and simply adding this single line:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

It will make it so any rules from the parent directory won't be applied. If the weirdness with PHP continues, you may want to check if there aren't any rules in your vhost/server config or that things like `Multiviews` are turned off (via `Options -Multiviews`).

Comment: Ok so if I took a default file that came with the WordPress install maDe a copy of it in the cpanel rename it remove the code and than put my code in it.

The file is found and it works. So im thinking the only thing left it could have been was a permissions problem. The permissions i put for the file when i uploaded it was 777. I know NOTHING about file permissions.

And i have been working on this for 5 hours and im done trying to figure out what the problem was it works..and im good with that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if I took a default file that came with the WordPress install made a copy of it in the cpanel rename it remove the code and than put my code in it.

The file is found and it works. So im thinking the only thing left it could have been was a permissions problem. The permissions i put for the file when i uploaded it was 777. I know NOTHING about file permissions.

And i have been working on this for 5 hours and im done trying to figure out what the problem was it works..and im good with that.